# What are the pros and cons of the single entity summon spells?

Tags: torchlight-2

Torchlight 2 offers several summon spells:

- Zombies
- Skeleton Archers
- Skeleton Warrior
- Blood Zombie
- Nether Imp

I often equip the first two on this list, simply because they seem to be the best options. Zombies do a decent amount of poison damage when they explode, and archers (though they cannot move around) generally offer a large DPS. The last three, however, I have never fully understood. **What are the pros and cons for the skeleton warrior, blood zombie, and nether imp?**

The blood skeleton in Torchlight 1 had a life steal capability, but blood zombie doesn't appear to have that. Why should I use these summons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skeleton warriors are a generic summon.  The benefit of using it on yourself is the cooldown is about 1/3 of the summon length, so you can have 3 or 4 of them at a time.  Their advantage over situational summons like zombies and archers is they move fast enough to keep up with you.  Their damage output is respectable as well.

The blood zombie does damage over time.

Nether Imp has the Silence ability.